# How can we transform the objective function of LQG problem as function of the estimation error?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, random-variables, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Consider an infinite-horizon classical Linear-Quadratic-Gaussian (LQG)
problem 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{x,u}{\min} &  & \underset{\eta\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{\mathbb{E}}\left[\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_{k=0}^{\eta-1}(x_{t}^{T}Qx_{t}+u_{t}^{T}Ru_{t})\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
for the discrete linear time invariant system 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{t+1} & = & Ax_{t}+Bu_{t}+w_{t},\\
y_{t} & = & Cx_{t}+v_{t},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $w_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,W)$ and $v_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,V)$
are independent sequences of iid zero-mean Gaussian random vectors
with covariance matrices $W\succ0$ and $V\succ0$. The initial condition
$x_{0}$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\overline{x}_{0}$
and covariance matrix $\overline{\Sigma}_{0},$ independent of the
noise processes $w_{t}$ and $v_{t}$.

How can we transform the objective function 
\begin{eqnarray*}
J & = & \underset{\eta\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{\mathbb{E}}\left[\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_{k=0}^{\eta-1}(x_{t}^{T}Qx_{t}+u_{t}^{T}Ru_{t})\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
as a function of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of of the estimation
error please? I know that we can transform $J$ in something that
looks like $Tr(Q\Sigma)+...$ Thanks